# Deviation of axis and breaks in image.plot from the fields package

Tags: r

Using `image.plot` from the R-package `fields` I get random deviations at the legend strip. As you can see in the images below the transition from one color to the next is not always exactly where the breaks are set. In the first picture for example the 500 break is a bit more to the left than the 500 on the axis. In the last picture it is more to the right.

In other examples I got even stronger deviations, but I tried to provide a minimal example to reproduce the phenomenon:

```
library("fields")
png("fields%03d.png", width=600)
for(seed in c(1,2,13)){
  set.seed(seed)
  mat <- matrix(runif(100, 0,3500), nrow=10)
  breaks <- c(0,seq(500, 3500, 1000))
  colors <- gray(seq(0, 1, length.out=length(breaks)-1))
  image.plot(mat, col=colors, breaks=breaks, horizontal=T)
}
dev.off()
```

Am I doing something wrong in defining the breaks and colors?

[image: random seed = 1]
[image: random seed = 2]
[image: random seed = 13]

My session info:

```
> sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.0 (2014-04-10)
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=de_DE.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=de_DE.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] grid      stats     graphics  grDevices utils    
[6] datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] fields_6.9.1      maps_2.3-6        spam_0.41-0      
[4] R.utils_1.29.8    R.oo_1.18.0       R.methodsS3_1.6.1

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] tools_3.1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

This was quite perplexing. You were not doing anything wrong; the function is just a bit funny with how it interprets those parameters. What `image.plot` does is break up the range of your observed data into `nlevels=` chunks. And essentially those chunks are plotted as the legend. So those chunk breaks might not line up exactly with the explicit breaks that you passed. This is why it is affected by the seed because each random set will have a different observed range and therefore different chunk breaks.

The second "problem" is that the legend is draw with the base `image` function. The image function interprets breaks as the midpoints of blocks of color rather than the edges as you would like to have them labeled. So in order to get color changes to appear at certain values, you have to reverse engineer the break points that would have resulted in that pattern.

So I need to do two things to "fix" this function. First i'll define a helper function that will do the calculations to find a seat of breaks to give you the labels where you like them. Here that function is

```
imagerev<-function(br, left=TRUE) {
    m<-length(br)
    n<-m-1
    A<-diag(n)
    if(left) {
        A[1,1:2]<-c(1.5,-.5)
        A[cbind(rep(2:n,each=2), as.vector(t(embed(1:n,2))))]<-.5
        br<-br[1:n]
    } else {
        A[n,(n-1):n]<-c(-.5,1.5)
        A[cbind(rep(1:(n-1),each=2), as.vector(t(embed(1:n,2))))]<-.5
        br<-br[2:m]
    }
    solve(A,br)
}
```

Now we need to trick `image.plot` into using this function to calculate y values for the legend. We will actually make a copy of the `image.plot` function and then replace one line of code to make this work.

```
image.plot2<-image.plot
body(image.plot2)[[17]]<-quote(iy<-imagerev(breaks))
```

Now we have a new function `image.plot2` which should do a better job of aligning color breaks to legend values. So let's test

```
set.seed(13)
mat <- matrix(runif(100, 0,3500), nrow=10)
breaks <- c(0,seq(500, 3500, 1000))
colors <- gray(seq(0, 1, length.out=length(breaks)-1))
image.plot2(mat, col=colors, breaks=breaks, horizontal=T, lab.breaks=breaks)
```

[image: updated output]

So you can see the alignment is better. But this method is by no means perfect. Using this reverse-engineering method it is simply impossible to recover the legend exactly except for very special cases. So I'm not sure what you especially like about this function; if it's just the color bar legend, you may have better results writing one yourself that doesn't use the `image` function. Maybe try `heatmap.2` or something.

Comment: Ok, so defenitely something has to be changed in the `image.plot` function. I think `image` is not made to get the transitions right. I would rather use `rect` or `polygon`. Since the package `fields` contains a function `poly.image` I would use this. It uses `polygon` to draw the image. I used it once to draw an image with logarithmic breaks and it worked quite well. I will contact the maintainer of the package and make him aware of this thread.